# How to set max zoom

Tags: here-api

So I noticed in the older version of the API there was a `maxZoomLevel` under `nokia.maps.map.Display`. However I can not find anything similar to this in the JS API 3.0.

Currently I am using

```
map.addEventListener('mapviewchange', function () {
    var zoom=map.getZoom();
    if(zoom<=maxZoom)  {
        map.setZoom(maxZoom)
    }
});
```

But once it hits the `maxZoom` and you zoom out more it is very choppy since it zooms out a bit then I set it back to `maxZoom`.  Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the max zoom for the layer, something like follow should work

```
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
defaultLayers.normal.map.setMax(12);

var map = new H.Map(mapContainer,
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:39.2328, lng:9.01168},
});
```

Comment: The object is a TileLayer: https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api/h-map-layer-tilelayer.html#h-map-layer-tilelayer

Answer (score 2):

Just a small addition on the accepted answer, if anyone is trying to use a vector layer, as provided in the here maps examples, then you just need to select the vector object, as done below:

```
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
defaultLayers.vector.normal.map.setMax(19); // this will set the max zoom level, so the user won't able to zoom deeper than 19 (close to buildings level)

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
            {
                center: currentAddress,
                zoom: 18 // this is the default zoom level
            });
```