# Min and max zoom in here api

Tags: here-api

Is there any way to actually set a min and max zoom on the map that would be run before the different event types.

Right now I have tried to add a listener on mapviewchange, mapviewchangeend, mapviewchangestart that manually set's the zoom, but it's a really hacky solution that makes the screen "jump".

I've looked through the documentation, but can't really find anything. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, we do not have a set of APIs to actively clip the min and max zoom.

However, on Android you can intercept the rendering thread and properly cap the zoom level without the jumping effect.

Please see [MapRenderListener](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-maprenderlistener.html) The method onPredraw() will callback just before the map is rendered. Here, you can get and set the zoom level and limit the zoom level as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been able to disable the double click and scroll wheel zoom, is there anyway to disable the pinch zoom? That way I could write my own functions for the zoom.

Comment: Are you using the JS API or android / ios?

Comment: Ah, sorry for not specifying. I'm using the javascript api.

Comment: I see, in this case hopefully our JS team member can help you out!

Comment: You can try something as follows : behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DBLTAPZOOM);

Comment: We have that disabled already, but what we want, as a backup solution if there is not min/max zoom, is a way to disable the pinch to zoom (which DPLTAMZOOM does not)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setMin/setMax methods on your tile layer. For example:

```
   var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();  
   defaultLayers.normal.map.setMax(12);
```

see also [How to set max zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635036/how-to-set-max-zoom)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reach a behaviour needed with

```
mapView.camera.limits.zoomRange = .init(kind: .zoomLevel, minimumValue: 2, maximumValue: 18)
```